# jQuery - how to call ajax when certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know you can use the function `setInterval` to call your ajax function at fixed time interval. What I'd like to achieve though is something like this:

```
while (true) //but obviously this while loop will block other code. I'd like it non-blocking
{   //if certain condition is met, call my ajax function.
}
```

so basically the code should sit silently in the background, listening. if certain condition is meet, fire ajax call.

Is is possible in jquery/javascript?

Edit: For conditions: basically, I will be automatically scrolling the rows of  a large table (that is another question, another post...), once it reaches the last row, the condition is met, ajax is called to fetch data from the server, re-populate the table, and start automatically scrolling again.

Comment: Please provide more info about condition type.

Comment: Or about the purpose of call.

Comment: use setInterval, and the code will setInterval to himself

Comment: `while (true)` will hit really hard the CPU. `var intervalID = setInterval(...` is better in your case.

Comment: @neo please explain under what circumstances your condition is being "met"

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, conditions do not "become met" all by themselves.

It's (mostly) a single threaded language, where the UI thread just sits around waiting for events to happen, and in response the programmer supplied event handlers go do stuff.  So long as they're doing stuff, the UI thread is unable to handle any more events.

This is why you shouldn't ever use a busy loop, or otherwise tie up the CPU doing long-winded calculations in a tight loop.

In summary, you shouldn't *ever* need to *poll* a condition - it should be evident when that condition becomes true because *some event will have fired, allowing it to become true*.

You should then be able to fire off your AJAX request *in that event's handler*.

---

**EDIT** you've now clarified that you want to do this when the scroll reaches the end of a table.

Per above, there is (of course) an *event* that tells you that something scrolled, and it'll tell you how far.

Look at `http://api.jquery.com/scroll/`

You need to register a handler for that event, and then trigger your AJAX call *in that handler*.

Comment: every case is a case... if is a javascript game needs a loop, then he need call a ajax to send a score to server like a sample

Comment: @GTSouza I already did, in my answer.  It is _impossible_ in JS for something to "become true" without it being in response to _some sort of event_.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly possible if you have an event. Then you can attach a handler to it. 
So the question is: what condition ?

Comment: how do i add a event listener for my ajax function, is there some sample code?